# Redirect request to Zend framework in the routeShutdown phase

Tags: php, zend-framework

We work with the Zend framework and perform CSRf checks on every controller action. I want to move this redundant logic to a point in the Zend lifecycle flow and though that the best place will be the routeShutdown method.

I tried to put there call for redirect - something like this:

```
$this->_redirector->gotoUrl(\)
```

What happens is an endless loop in which the request eventually times out.

I must be doing something extremely wrong but since I am a newbie in this, I can't figure out what - any help will be most appreciated.

Thanks
A.

Comment: How will the above compile (/interpret)? (\)  looks invalid. Did you mean ("\")?

Comment: you are right off course, i wrote from memory - here is the actual line:
$redirector->gotoUrl('/');

Comment: My last php contact is a few years back in the past, but from a logical view: gotoUrl sounds like it redirects to a URL. So if its your own host then you have a recursion. Maybe you were looking for some kind of alias setting in your web server instead?

Comment: you are right - this was the issue. filtering by controller solved this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Thomas Killan was right - i entered a loop. filtering according to the controller and action fixed this.